# Streamsets gives this error trying to parse a valid JSON

Tags: streamsets, buffer-overrun

I am setting up streamsets for a project.It has Kafka consumer as its origin. It was working fine for smaller messages but when the message size is larger it throws this error.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input in field name at [Source: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.ext.io.OverrunReader@39c37ffd; line: 1, column: 4191
```

I have already set Max Object Length (chars) to 1000000 and parser.limit property to 10335040.
I am unable to figure out this issue.

NA

Complete stack trace is

```
KAFKA_37 - Cannot parse record from message 'rms-search-data::0::61950': com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input in field name at [Source: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.ext.io.OverrunReader@39c37ffd; line: 1, column: 4191]
com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.OnRecordErrorException: KAFKA_37 - Cannot parse record from message 'rms-search-data::0::61950': com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input in field name
 at [Source: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.ext.io.OverrunReader@39c37ffd; line: 1, column: 4191]
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.kafka.BaseKafkaSource.processKafkaMessageDefault(BaseKafkaSource.java:265)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.kafka.BaseKafkaSource.processKafkaMessageDefault(BaseKafkaSource.java:224)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.kafka.StandaloneKafkaSource.produce(StandaloneKafkaSource.java:86)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.configurablestage.DSource.produce(DSource.java:38)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.lambda$execute$2(StageRuntime.java:283)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.impl.CreateByRef.call(CreateByRef.java:40)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:235)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:298)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StagePipe.process(StagePipe.java:219)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.processPipe(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:810)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.runPollSource(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:554)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.run(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:383)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:527)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipeline.run(ProductionPipeline.java:109)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunnable.run(ProductionPipelineRunnable.java:75)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.standalone.StandaloneRunner.start(StandaloneRunner.java:703)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.AsyncRunner.lambda$start$3(AsyncRunner.java:151)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:226)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:222)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:226)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.metrics.MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService$MetricsTask.run(MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input in field name
 at [Source: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.ext.io.OverrunReader@39c37ffd; line: 1, column: 4191]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:483)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parseName2(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1716)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parseName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1700)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:921)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:493)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:362)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3786)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1627)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:126)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:517)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:362)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3786)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1627)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:126)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:517)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:362)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3786)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1627)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:126)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:517)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:362)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3786)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1627)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:126)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl$MapDeserializer.deserialize(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3786)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1627)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.JsonObjectReaderImpl.readObjectFromStream(JsonObjectReaderImpl.java:199)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.readObjectFromStream(OverrunJsonObjectReaderImpl.java:196)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.json.JsonObjectReaderImpl.read(JsonObjectReaderImpl.java:111)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.parser.json.JsonCharDataParser.parse(JsonCharDataParser.java:70)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.parser.WrapperDataParserFactory$WrapperDataParser.lambda$parse$0(WrapperDataParserFactory.java:105)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.impl.CreateByRef.call(CreateByRef.java:40)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.parser.WrapperDataParserFactory$WrapperDataParser.parse(WrapperDataParserFactory.java:105)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.kafka.BaseKafkaSource.processKafkaMessageDefault(BaseKafkaSource.java:244)
    ... 29 more
```

This json fails:-

{"payload":{"data":{"aIndex":"application0502","aType":"application","pIndex":"profile000","pType":"profile","da":{"clientId":"168613","clientType":"1","statusDataList":{"68348":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68348","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68349":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68349","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68351":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68351","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68365":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68365","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68366":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68366","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68367":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68369":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68370":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68371":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68372":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"}},"recruiterId":"76866550","isActivity":false},"ignoreParamsForIndexing":{"statusDetailsForAsyncActions":{"clientId":"168613","statusId":"1949","subStatusId":null,"assessmentTestId":"","feedbackFormIds":[],"hiring managers":[],"isBillingEnabled":null,"isOfferGenerationEnabled":null,"statusDataJson":{"assessment":{"action":1,"sendToNew":false,"resendToAll":false,"statusId":"1949","subStatusId":null},"CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59"}},"projectDetailsForAsyncActions":{"projectId":"15463"}},"optn":{"_routing":"168613"},"action":22,"activityField":"STATUS_CHANGED"},"dataArray":null,"retryCount":3,"additionalHeaders":{},"routingKey":"168613","topic":"rms-search-data"},"headers":{"AppId":123,"SystemId":"1234","X-TRANSACTION-ID":"27108593751"}}

This Json gives success:-

{"payload":{"data":{"aIndex":"application0502","aType":"application","pIndex":"profile000","pType":"profile","da":{"clientId":"168613","clientType":"1","statusDataList":{"68348":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68348","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68349":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68349","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68351":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68351","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68365":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68365","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68366":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68366","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68367":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68369":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68370":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"},"68371":{"PAYMENT_STATUS":1,"UNIQUE_KEY":"168613_68367","CURR_STATUS":"1949","CURR_SUB_STATUS":null,"STATUS_VALUE":1949,"SUB_STATUS_VALUE":null,"STATUS_STATE":0,"OWNERS_BY_CURR_STATUS":[],"ADDITIONAL_OWNERS":[],"CURR_STATUS_UPDATEDBY":"76866550","CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:19:00","REQ_EMPLOYERID":"4103","REQ_POSTED_BY":"76866550"}},"recruiterId":"76866550","isActivity":false},"ignoreParamsForIndexing":{"statusDetailsForAsyncActions":{"clientId":"168613","statusId":"1949","subStatusId":null,"assessmentTestId":"","feedbackFormIds":[],"hiring managers":[],"isBillingEnabled":null,"isOfferGenerationEnabled":null,"statusDataJson":{"assessment":{"action":1,"sendToNew":false,"resendToAll":false,"statusId":"1949","subStatusId":null},"CURR_STATUS_DATE":"2019-05-21 17:18:59"}},"projectDetailsForAsyncActions":{"projectId":"15463"}},"optn":{"_routing":"168613"},"action":22,"activityField":"STATUS_CHANGED"},"dataArray":null,"retryCount":3,"additionalHeaders":{},"routingKey":"168613","topic":"rms-search-data"},"headers":{"AppId":123,"SystemId":"1234","X-TRANSACTION-ID":"27108593751"}}

Comment: If anyone knows about the solution please help

Comment: Can you post the JSON? Is there any possibility it may be badly formed? Have you tried validating it?

Comment: Yes I have validated it many times. i have tested it manually. It starts throwing this error after the json exceeds some limit .

Comment: I have posted the json which gives success and the one which fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick pipeline to try to replicate this, but it works as I would expect. I had to set **Max Object Length (chars)** in the Kafka Consumer's Data Format configuration, as you did, and it read and parsed the data just fine.

Check whether the data is being retrieved from Kafka intact: duplicate the pipeline, change the Data Format of the Kafka Consumer to `Text`, and send the output to a file. You should be able to see if all of the data is being read from the Kafka topic. It's possible that the maximum message size in Kafka has been set to 4k, and this results in messages being truncated.

Another thing to check is that you are using the correct stage library. In fact, as explained in the comments, this was the fix - Deep was using the CDH 2.x consumer; when he changed it to Kafka 0.11.0.0 it started working correctly.

Comment: Hi, THanks for the help ,atleast i started looking in the correct direction, i checked my consumer settings in pipeline, i was using cdh 2.x consumer, i changed it to kafka 0.11.0.0 and its working fine now.

Comment: Could you write this as an answer to help others searching on the same problem?

Comment: Some how they have blocked me from posting answers

Comment: No comment - I just added it to my answer. Could you upvote and accept it so that others can see the fix? Thanks!